Show that for all $f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ there's a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ that converges pointwise to $f$.
Let $X$ be a Hausdorff $\sigma$-compact space and $\mathcal{F}\subseteq C(X,\mathbb{R})$ be a subalgebra that separates points of $X$. Show that for all continuous functions $f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ there's a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ that converges pointwise to $f$.
This result is stated in the proof of the 6.10.8. Corollary of the book "Measure Theory" written by V.I. Bogachev.

What I did:
Let $\{K_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a collection of compact sets such that $X=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}K_i$ and $K_i\subseteq K_{i+1}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.
Using the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem we can conclude that for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a sequence $(f_{i,n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{i,n}(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in K_i$. However, I don't know how to use this fact to obtain the desired result.

I just noted that proof is quite simple: for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ choose $f_n\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<2^{-n}$ for all $x\in X$.

Correction: $x\in K_n$.

FYI This kind of technique (you have a sequence of sequences and you want to extract a converging sequence and you do so by choosing one element in each sequence "far enough down the line" is sometimes called diagonalisation trick.
